# Set a location in a Https Callable function on Firebase 9 (stripe customer portal)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set up a button for the user to manage his subscription with Stripe Customer Portal and their Firebase's integration.

Problem, the documentation is valid for the old version of Firebase (8) and I'm using the new one, Firebase 9.

We are on the client side and this is React.js.

This is their js code for calling the function (you can see the complete code here: https://github.com/stripe-samples/firebase-subscription-payments/blob/master/public/javascript/app.js):

```
const functionLocation = 'us-east1';
    
const functionRef = firebase
      .app()
      .functions(functionLocation)
      .httpsCallable('ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink');
    const { data } = await functionRef({ returnUrl: window.location.origin });
    window.location.assign(data.url);
  });
```

With Firebase 9 it should be something like this:

```
const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp)

export async function goToBillingPortal() {
       const functionRef = httpsCallable(functions, 'ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink');
    
       const { data } = await functionRef({ returnUrl: window.location.origin });
       window.location.assign(data.url);
 }
```

The console displays 3 errors:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-xxxxxxxxd76.cloudfunctions.net/ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

service.ts:206 POST https://us-central1-xxxxxxx76.cloudfunctions.net/ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink net::ERR_FAILED

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: internal
```

Apparently, the problem is that I need to specify the location of the server (ex. us-central1) but I can't understand how to it with Firebase 9. All the guides are for Firebase 8.

I've tried different things like:

```
const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp).location("us-central1")
```

or

```
const functionRef = httpsCallable(functions, 'ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink').location("us-central1")
```

but it doesn't work.

Ideas?

Comment: If the target function doesn't exist at that URL, you will get CORS errors as the function handles the negotiation - you won't get a `404 Not Found` error. Make sure to check the actual function URL (remember to deploy your function too) and also copy the URL in the error to check it in your browser.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the name, they changed it. LOL now it works!

Answer (score 6):

As shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/functions.md#getfunctions) in the doc, you should pass the region as the second parameter of the `getFunctions()` method:

```
 const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp, "europe-west1");
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that. Unfortunately I still get the same 3 errors, so apparently the problem is something else :(

Comment: It seems you have a cors problem. Are you using the emulator? Can you try to deploy your Cloud Function and call it from a deployed app.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was using the localhost (npm start). Just tried to deploy it and call it from the deployed app but it doesn't work. I see the same 3 errors in the console.

Comment: Can you share the code of your Cloud Function? Also can you try with one of the (simple) examples of the Callable Functions doc.

Comment: I'm using the Firebase/Stripe extension, so the source code should be this one (made by stripe): https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts

Comment: Did you choose the `us-central` Region? If yes, normally you should not configure any region since it’s the default one.

Comment: tbh I don't remember if I chose it, but in my Functions' dashboard I see that the region is "us-central1" for every function

Answer (score 0):

One can also define where to deploy with `.region()`, which I think even accepts a list:

```
const CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_REGION = "us-east1";

exports.billing_portal = functions.region( CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_REGION ).https.onCall(
    async (data, context: CallableContext) => {
      
    }
);
```